# how to unzip and untar using python?

Tags: python, extract, tar, gunzip

So I need to access the files and the folders within the zipped folder(also tar). The user gives the path where this Gunzip file is present and from the python code, I need to unzip, untar and extract all these files to the same location and then access the files and folders within this directory.

```
path given by user - C:/Users/user1/Desktop/tar_gz/tarball.tar.xz
```

the files should be extracted to the same directory - C:/Users/user1/Desktop/tar_gz/tarball

I'm new to the concepts of machine learning and having a difficult time figuring this out. Is there any approach to do this?

Answer (score 2):

[Python tarfile module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html)

```
import tarfile
import os

path_tofile = r"C:/Users/user1/Desktop/tar_gz/tarball.tar.xz"
extract_direcotry = os.path.dirname(path_tofile)

if tarfile.is_tarfile(path_tofile):
    with tarfile.open(path_tofile) as f:
        f.extractall(path=extract_direcotry)  # Extract all members from the archive to the current working directory
```